# Watch doesn't fire when I write the same value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have  a watch

```
 $scope.$watchCollection('[deal.curr1, deal.curr2]', function (newValues) {
      ...
        }
```

I then change the value in code:

```
$scope.deal.curr1 ="USD";
```

But in a case curr1 was already "USD", 
watch wont be called.
But I would like  it to be called anyway.
Setting null before doesn't help.

```
$scope.deal.curr1 =null;
 $scope.deal.curr1 ="USD";
```

Answer (score 0):

setting null and then other value won't work because the evals are done after each cycle if you waned to do that you would have to set it to null and then use $timeout.

```
  $scope.var=null
  $timeout(function(){
       $scope.val="value";
  })
```

To assign the new value on the next cycle, but this would run the validation twice.

now the question is. Why would you want to run the the watch function if the value remains the same? this a protection to avoid making unnecessary calls and improve performance. if the value doesn't change there shouldn't be a valid reason for the watcher to react.

If you still must i'll advice to observe other parameter if possible that would give some indication that some action took place.

could you elaborate more in your use case?

Comment: I have a deal object in the scope with curr1 value. When the user presses the "Clear" button, I set deal to {}, and initialize deal properties . one of the properties is curr. The code is actually $scope.deal.curr1 =getCurrency().  where the function getCurrency gets the value from $http callback function. In the watch I initialize other properties of deal, which depend on curr.

Comment: add a timestamp and watch for that

Comment: solutions are usually simple, if you find your self in a too complicated solution, reconsider your path or your tools ;)

Answer (score 0):

The listener only gets fired when the watchExpression is different in the last two calls. Since you just want to fire the listener, you can just call it manually. [Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope)

EDIT: since the listener is always called after the $http call, just call the listener in the success handler of the $http promise and ditch $watchCollection

```
$http(...).then(function(payload){
   //things you do with the resonse. like setting $scope.deal.curr1 
   $scope.listener(newVal);
}, function(reason){...})
```

Comment: Also the code is actually  $scope.deal.curr1 =getCurrency(). where the function getCurrency gets the value from $http call.  I want to call the listener  after curr1 gets its value.